# How to get the specific FlowElement under the cursor or selection

Tags: tlf

I have a TextFlow that has an SelectionManager attached. I'd like to get the FlowElement that the cursor is inside of or if multiple lines are selected that the selection is inside of.

```
_textFlow.addEventListener(SelectionEvent.SELECTION_CHANGE,selectionChangeListener,false,0,true);


private function selectionChangeListener(e:SelectionEvent):void
{               
    var selectionState:SelectionState = e.selectionState;
    var selectedElementRange:ElementRange = ElementRange.createElementRange(selectionState.textFlow, selectionState.absoluteStart, selectionState.absoluteEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to find the **leaf element** with the following method but still do not know how to find the **element** that contains the **selection**.

```
/** Returns the current FlowELement element at the currentStyleLevel */
private function currentStyleElement(absolutePosition:int):FlowElement
{
    var e:FlowElement;
    switch(currentStyleLevel)
    {
        case TextFlow:
            e = _textFlow;
            break;
        case ParagraphElement:
            e = _textFlow.findLeaf(absolutePosition).getParagraph();
            break;
        default:
            e = _textFlow.findLeaf(absolutePosition);
    }
    return e;
}
```